# PHP page redirect

Tags: php, redirect, header

Can PHP make a redirect call after executing a function?  I am creating a function on the completion of which I want it to redirect to a file located in the same root folder.  Can it be done?

```
if (...) {
    // I am using echo here.
} else if ($_SESSION['qnum'] > 10) { 
    session_destroy();
    echo "Some error occured.";
    // Redirect to "user.php".
}
```

Comment: I serach about this and i find related this answer in 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539752/redirect-function/13539808

Answer (score 302, accepted):

Yes, you would use the [header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

```
/* Redirect browser */
header("Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/user.php"); 
exit();
```

It is a good practice to call `exit()` right after it so that code below it does not get executed.

Also, from the documentation:

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include(), or require(), functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

This means you should not echo anything right before the `header()` function, as doing so will more than likely throw an error. Also, you will need to verify that this code gets run before any other output as well.

Comment: You should also set the HTTP Status to 302.

Comment: "The second special case is the "Location:" header. Not only does it send this header back to the browser, but it also returns a REDIRECT (302) status code to the browser unless the 201 or a 3xx status code has already been set."

Comment: I'm bothered by "afterwords".

Comment: Use `die` instead of `exit` to prevent only exiting the function.

Answer (score 52):

Using a javascript as a failsafe will ensure the user is redirected (even if the headers have already been sent). Here you go:

```
// $url should be an absolute url
function redirect($url){
    if (headers_sent()){
      die('<script type="text/javascript">window.location=\''.$url.'\';</script‌​>');
    }else{
      header('Location: ' . $url);
      die();
    }    
}
```

If you need to properly handle relative paths, I've written a function for that (but that's outside the scope of the question).

Comment: how descriptive.

Comment: Change this line to this and it will... `die('<script type="text/javascript">window.location=\''.$url.'\';</script>');`

Comment: The above function with Gabe's fix works!

Comment: fine unless user has JS disabled.

Comment: In which case you could use a meta redirect `die('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=' . $url . '" />');`

Answer (score 17):

Simple way is to use:

```
  echo '<script>window.location.href = "the-target-page.php";</script>';
```

Answer (score 13):

```
   $url='the/url/you/want/to/go';
   echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT="1; '.$url.'">';
```

this works for me fine.

Comment: this works for me too. Thanks

Comment: Worked for me as well

Comment: Yep, this was a life-saver for me; I dynamically populate page titles and body ids from a header include so no matter what, I was always going to have sent headers. And for me this is just a web form bot response. Nice one, thanks.

Comment: this worked for me too. :)
don't know why this is not at the top. :(

Comment: this worked for me also. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

```
header( "Location: http://www.domain.com/user.php" );
```

But you can't first do an echo, and then redirect.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

    http_redirect("relpath", array("name" => "value"), true, HTTP_REDIRECT_PERM);

?>
```

Comment: Note that http_redirect is part of PECL pecl_http that is not built into PHP by default.

Answer (score 3):

As metioned by **nixxx** adding `ob_start()` before adding any php code will prevent the headers already sent error.

It worked for me

The code below also works. But it first loads the page and then redirects  when I use it.

```
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT="1; '.$redirect_url.'">';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to redirect in [php](http://www.codingku.com)

```
<?php
/* Redirect browser */
header("Location: http://example.com/");
/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

In essence, as long as nothing is output, you can do whatever you want (kill a session, remove user cookies, calculate Pi to 'n' digits, etc.) prior to issuing a location header.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to include the redirect in your php file without necessarily having it at the top, you can activate output buffering at the top, then call redirect from anywhere within the page. Example;

```
 <?php
 ob_start(); //first line
 ... do some work here
 ... do some more
 header("Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/user.php"); 
 exit();
 ... do some work here
 ... do some more
```

Answer (score -1):

The [header()](http://php.net/header) function does this:

```
header("Location: user.php");
```

Comment: Please use absolute URLs according to the HTTP specification.

Comment: True, but make sure you remove the echo first or you might experience a "Headers allready send" ;)