# PHP clear browser cache to avoid form data resend after refresh

Tags: php, caching, browser

I'm developing a PHP-MySQL app that enables registered users to enter text comments.  Problem is:

1. User sign-in into the web site - OKAY
2. User presented with a form to submit text comment - OKAY
3. User enters text comment and submits - OKAY
4. I have a routine that sanitize the comment & save it into MySQL (with userid, textcomment, datetime stamp) & present back the user that his/her comment is entered - OKAY
5. User decides to refresh browser - a duplicate comment is entered - BAD!

I was thinking 3 options:

- OPTION 1: Routine that checks: last time user posted comment, and if so, check if this is a duplicate. If duplicate then display error message.
- OPTION 2: Routine that does not allow a user to post too quickly. So basically do not allow postings of comments within 1 minute or so. So if browser is refreshed the comment will be ignored.
- OPTION 3: Manipulate the browser cache to clear out its contents so when refreshed no duplicate will be entered.

Now in the context of my application, my concerns with OPTION 1 and OPTION 2 is performance PHP-MySQL since I already have various queries within the same page that push/get data from databases. So OPTION 3 may target the issue differently.

Questions is: If I go for OPTION 3 can this be considered a Best Practice? meaning clearing the browser cache is the best most effective solution? I have read that there are consequences too? your thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do a redirect after submitting data to the database. It's a common practise.

An [http redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection) instructs the browser to issue an http `GET` for the url specified (as opposed to the http `POST` that is used to submit the form) . If you do this right after you have inserted data into the database, when the user refreshes his browser nothing will happen other than him seeing the same page again.

[This question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112373/php-page-redirect) tells how you redirect with php.

Comment: Sorry my ignorance what do you mean by a redirect?

Comment: By redirect he means send an HTTP status 302. Check out the PHP documentation for the header method: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php - search for "Location:"

Comment: Understood, so I will issue a redirect to the same page right after inserting data. Now, Can this cover me from the 'back' button? meaning user clicks BACK and resubmitt?

Comment: @Thilo: [303](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.4) would be the appropriate status code for a redirection on POST.

Comment: I tested it and it works, basically I did exactly as you said, after INSERTING to database I did a header("location:...) and works wonders! thanks

Answer (score 4):

Just unset the posted variable after you have inserted it in the database

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["comment"])){
        //store in the database
        //on successful storage
        unset($_POST["comment"]);
    }
?>
```

Thus the value won't be posted back when user refreshes the page...

Comment: This doesent work - the data is stored in the browser and unsetting it wont help (i wish it would... a redirect means time...)

Comment: For me unsetting of the post-data right after the successfull login does the trick. And then if the user goes one step back in browser-history the data ist lost and can't be found by the browser. Job done ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Comment: Unfortunately I am using apache_mod_rewrite for most of the pages, so displaying a GET on the resulting page is not an option. Otherwise I will break the mod_rewrite rulest, I guess

Comment: That is completely independent from the pattern. Just take care that you redirect to the correct URL.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Option 4: Use a one-time form token that authenticates the form request. If the request was successful, invalidate the token.

When doing this, even returning to the form after a redirection won’t allow it to send the form again. Additionally, this will also make CSRF attacks harder.

Comment: I may agree with your Option4, unfortunately I am not using SESSION variables at this time and It is not desirable add additional SQL tables at this time to store those values neither

Answer (score 0):

After entering data into database redirect the page using header or location.href

Answer (score -4):

i have found new way try this.

```
   function PreventResendData($invalidpage='index.php'){

    if(   $_POST && !is_array( $_SESSION['post_var'] )   ) {

        $_SESSION['post_var'] = $_POST;
        header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

    }
    else if($_SESSION['post_var'])
    {
        $_POST = $_SESSION['post_var']; 
        $_SESSION['post_var'] = '';
    }
    else
    {
        header("location:".$invalidpage);
    }

}
```