# redirect to different page in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP page redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112373/php-page-redirect)

I have 0 experience with PHP. I was setting up a blog in wordpress which is in PHP.

In a page there are includes. Now I do I redirect users from page to the other.

For example: When users visit pics.php I want to redirect them to Gallery.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112373/php-page-redirect

Comment: yes ... you search first is located in the top right side of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the users browser via the [`header()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function:

```
header( "Location: gallery.php" );
```

You will need to ensure that no output has been sent before this line (check for `echo` and `print` statements, as well as anything that may produce errors or warnings).

Answer (score 1):

See [header](http://php.net/header):

```
header('Location: http://domain.com/Gallery.php');
```

Comment: Voted this up, because the Location header officially requires a full domain path (although relative paths work virtually everywhere).

Answer (score 0):

Read manual for [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

If the *Location* header is modified, the browser will make a new request to the specified URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location: /Gallery.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
header('Location: /pics.php');
```

or

```
header('Location: http://www.mydomain.com/header.php');
```