# How to rewrite url from id to slug

Tags: .htaccess, url, seo, url-rewriting, slug

I am developing a site and the products displayed on site contains url like

> product details page -->

```
mysite.com/jeans/details.php?id=1
```

I want to convert it to

```
mysite.com/jeans/details.php?slug.php
```

> slug = new-jeans-america

I want to convert it to

```
mysite.com/jeans/details.php?new-jeans-america.php
```

How can I do this ?? Can anyone suggest an **htaccess** rewrite code ?

I am really new to htaccess .

Comment: And what is expected  slug for "details.php?id= **2** ?

Comment: i have mentioned slug = new-jeans-america

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create friendly URLs with .htaccess?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033407/how-can-i-create-friendly-urls-with-htaccess)

Comment: So `slug` should change according to `id` right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I rewrite a name to an id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22576324/how-do-i-rewrite-a-name-to-an-id)

Comment: yes @anubhava table contains field of slug , i want to display the slug and not the id

Comment: Then it has to be done via PHP code as htaccess cannot query your database.

Comment: can you guide me further please i tried the other method which Sumurai8 told but it didnt work .. as it has a function name getseoname() which is not defined so i dont know what would it do ...