# Redirect does not work when method/route is called trough AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, routes

I have this code on `listDevice.html.twig` template.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://dev/app_dev.php/device/" + window.id + "/remove",
    crossDomain: false,
    dataType: "html",
    error: function(data) {
        console.log("Error in Processing-----" + data.status);
    }
});
```

The code is triggered when someone click on `delete` button (doesn't matter). And this is the function that handle the deletion at `DeleteController.php`:

```
/**
 * @Route("/device/{id}/remove",  name="device_remove")
 * @param integer $id
 * @param Request $request
 * @Method({"GET"})
 * @Template()
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
 * @return array
 */
public function removeAction(Request $request, $id = null)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $can_delete = $em->getRepository('DeviceBundle:UnassignedDevices')->findBy(array('id' => $id));

    if (count($can_delete) == 0) {
        $driverHasDevice = $em->getRepository("DeviceBundle:DriverHasDevice")->findOneBy(array('device' => $id));
        $deviceToRemove = $em->getRepository("DeviceBundle:Device")->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));

        if ($driverHasDevice) {
            $em->remove($driverHasDevice);
        }

        $em->remove($deviceToRemove);
        $em->flush();

        $flashMessage = $this->get('translator')->trans('delete.success', array('%element%' => 'device'));
    }
    else {
        $flashMessage = $this->get('translator')->trans('devices.messages.driver.assigned');
    }

    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('message', $flashMessage);
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('device_list'));
}
```

Both works fine, I mean when I click on `delete` button the route matches and the code is executed but the redirect, this line, `$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('device_list'));` never happen, why is that? How I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `$this->redirect` does is basically returning response with `302` http status, which is redirect. This won't be parsed by ajax call (it waits for `200 OK` status) so you can't do it this way.

Other solution for what you want to achieve is returning regular (`json` in my example) response, containing your url you want to perform redirect to, and do it in your `success` callback by setting `window.location.href`:

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://dev/app_dev.php/device/" + window.id + "/remove",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function(data) {
        console.log("Error in Processing-----" + data.status);
    },
    success: function(urlFromController) {
        window.location.href = urlFromController;
    }
});
```

Your controller:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
public function removeAction(Request $request, $id = null)
{
    (...)

    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('message', $flashMessage);
    return new JsonResponse($this->generateUrl('device_list'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably returning a raw html string to your ajax call.  I did some research.  I believe you need to this instead:

```
header("Location:" + $this->generateUrl('device_list')); /* Redirect browser */
exit();
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112373/php-page-redirect) for a more detailed description.

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "http://dev/app_dev.php/device/" + window.id + "/remove",
crossDomain: false,
dataType: "html",
complete: function (data) {  // add this option and see what "data" is
    console.log(data);
},
error: function(data) {
    console.log("Error in Processing-----" + data.status);
}
```

});

Comment: Can you add the complete option as in the code I just added and see what data is returning?

Comment: `console.log` outputs nothing, I just get the complete HTML code

Comment: Ok, and that's with your original php or the php I posted?

Comment: Can you post what you're getting back.  You say it logs nothing, but you get the html back??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56981/discussion-between-reynierpm-and-joshboley).