# PHP: Redirect to another page after HTML form executes a php script (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I got a HTML form on a wordpress website which executes a PHP script after submitting. That works fine, but after the PHP script is executed I need to redirect to another wordpress page, does anyone knows how I could do that?

Here's the HTML code on my Wordpress page:

```
<form action="[insert_php] include('wp-content/logindataupload.php');         
[/insert_php]" method="post" >First name
<input name="field1" type="text" />
Name
<input name="field2" type="text" />
E-Mail
<input name="field3" type="text" />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>
```

And here's the code in the "logindataupload.php" file:

```
<?php
 $path = 'wp-content/uploadhistory.txt';

 if (isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2']) && isset($_POST['field3'])) {
    $fh = fopen($path,"a+");
    $string = $_POST['field1'].$_POST['field2'].'_'.$_POST['field3']."\n";
    fwrite($fh,$string); // Write information to the file
    fclose($fh); // Close the file
 }

 $path2 = 'wp-content/currentupload.txt';

 file_put_contents($path2, "");

 if (isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2']) && isset($_POST['field3'])) {
    $fh = fopen($path2,"a+");
    $string = $_POST['field1'].$_POST['field2'].'_'.$_POST['field3'];
    fwrite($fh,$string); // Write information to the file
    fclose($fh); // Close the file
 }

?>
```

I'm quite new into PHP and I think I have to do the redirect in the "logindataupload.php" file. I already tried to insert the following behind the last "?>"

```
header("Location: http://page-i-want-to-redirect-to.com"); /* Redirect browser */
```

If something's missing, please tell me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: _behind the last "?>"_  - well since it is a PHP function, it would obviously belong _into_ `<?php ... ?>` tags, otherwise it is just _text_ ...

Comment: sorry I wrote wrong... I mean I inserted it before the las "?>"...

Comment: Well then your question is lacking the actual _problem_ description. Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2']) && isset($_POST['field3'])) {
$fh = fopen($path,"a+");
$string = $_POST['field1'].$_POST['field2'].'_'.$_POST['field3']."\n";
fwrite($fh,$string); // Write information to the file
fclose($fh); // Close the file
header("Location: logindataupload.php");
exit();
}
```

use the header function like this if this didnt work just add ob_start(); at the beginning of the  page

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, I tried this (both, with and without the "ob_start();") but then after submitting I just get a plank page...

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but its a bit long.

> does anyone knows how I could do that?

Yes - and your question should be closed as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112373/php-page-redirect) or many others here on SO.

> I'm quite new into PHP

By the look of things you are new to computers and programming. Writing to flat files on a multi-user system is not a recipe for a successful outcome.

Copying the same blocks of code and injecting different variable settings in between is not good programming practice.

Comment: yes sorry, I know I'm not that good at programming... but I try it hard to get into it...

And it's not exactly the same question as those you show me, because I have that script inbetween, I saw these other posts, but I couldn't fix my issue with theese...