# Javascript window.location.href and window.alert

Tags: javascript, alert, location-href

How can Javascript window.location.href and window.alert can work together inside if else cycle?

I have the following code to insert data inside an SQL table. If something wrong, a notice message appear (Notice: Undefined variable: code1 in......) for just a second because of window.location.href redirection and the alert (messagebox) don't appear.

```
if(isset($_POST['add_item'])){
    $edit_id = $_POST['edit_id'];
    $code = $_POST['code'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (code) 
                       VALUES ('$code1')";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="page.php"</script>';
    } else {
        //echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Error: ' . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error .'")</script>';
        }   
}
```

$code1 inside VALUES into $SQL was deliberately placed to generate the error. Is there a way to redirect if all is OK and open the messagebox if an error appear

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112373/php-page-redirect

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `header()` on server side if you want to forward:

```php
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        header("Location: page.php");
    } else {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Error: ' . $sql . "\n" . $conn->error .'")</script>';
//use backslash for break in alert…
        }
```

BTW: don't forget semicolon terminating each line…

AND USE PREPARED STATEMENTS!

Comment: don't work and also the notice just for a second do not appera

Comment: does it give a error or what doesn't work?

Comment: And what do you mean by "also the notice just for a second do not appera "?

Comment: With the code I wrote, for a second, appear:" Notice: Undefined variable: code1 in......" with your code nothing (notice/error) appear because of the page reload