# open url from php snippet in chrome

Tags: php

In one of scripts I use daily I have something like this:

```php
<?php

$args = explode("\n", $argv[1]);

// loop through args
foreach ($args as $arg) {
    
    // create the url
    $url = 'https://trends.google.pl/trends/explore?date=now%207-d&geo=PL&q=,' . urlencode(trim($arg));

    // open the url in the default browser
    shell_exec('open ' . escapeshellarg($url));
}

?>
```

How to change this part

```php
// open the url in the default browser
    shell_exec('open ' . escapeshellarg($url));
```

to open the URL in chrome browser? Because for now it opens it in default browser and I don't want to change the default browser to chrome in my os (macos)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP page redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112373/php-page-redirect)

Comment: @kiner_shah i think want to open browser with that url using the CLI

Comment: Which OS? Also, have you already researched what commands you can use on your CLI to open a browser?

Comment: macos, I have no idea what cli is.

Comment: @MichalK what's the problem it won't open? or something error? did you try to debug and check the url contain using var_dump or print?

Comment: there is no problem at all with this code, it just opens the URL in default browser. and I would like to open it in CHROME

Comment: No need to set Chrome as the default (unless you want it as default all the time). Just call chrome specifically instead of just "open". Something like: `shell_exec('chrome ' . escapeshellarg($url));` (not sure what the executable is called on MacOS)

Comment: shell_exec('open -a "Google Chrome" '.escapeshellarg($url)); ?

Comment: @Jerson it works! Thanks! You can add a standalone reply and I will accept it if you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use -a flags and the application name

```
shell_exec('open -a "Google Chrome" '.escapeshellarg($url));
```